# how to unpack a nested list in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, nested

How to unpack a list, which is nested inside another list. 
Practically to transform this:

```
l=['aa','bb',['ccc','ddd'],'ee']
```

to

```
l=['aa','bb','ccc','ddd','ee']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) and e. g. the solution of [elqott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781252/1797098)

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> l = ['1','2',['3','4'],'5'] 
>>> flatten(l)
```

Following your edit

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> l = ['aa','bb',['ccc','ddd'],'ee'] 
>>> flatten(l)
['aa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ee']
```